# Iwlwifi (dvm), debugfs and fixing rate

Tags: linux, drivers, intel, iwlwifi

In the source code of the iwlwifi dvm linux driver, there is a function named « rs_program_fix_rate » ( https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/dvm/rs.c#L334 )

The source claims:

```
/**
 * Program the device to use fixed rate for frame transmit
 * This is for debugging/testing only
 * once the device start use fixed rate, we need to reload the module
 * to being back the normal operation.
 */
```

To interact with this function, I reckon from the source code you can use the DEBUGFS filesystem and the file: `/sys/kernel/debug/ieee80211/phy0/netdev:wlp2s0/stations/MAC_ADRESS/rate_scale_table`, by executing for example `echo "0x2C104" | tee >./rate_scale_table`.

I have multiple questions about this:

How is constructed the hexadecimal string you write into this file? The "0x2C104" appears in the output of the file `rate_scale_table` which looks like this:

```
sta_id 0
failed=0 success=0 rate=0FFF
fixed rate 0x2C104
valid_tx_ant ANT_A,ANT_B,
lq type legacy
last tx rate=0x4009
general: flags=0x8 mimo-d=0 s-ant=0x1 d-ant=0x3
agg: time_limit=4000 dist_start_th=3 frame_cnt_limit=63
reduced tpc=0
single stream params: INVALID
Start idx [0]=0x0 [1]=0x0 [2]=0x0 [3]=0x0
 rate[0] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[1] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[2] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[3] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[4] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[5] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[6] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[7] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[8] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[9] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[10] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[11] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[12] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[13] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[14] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC
 rate[15] 0x2C104 HT | ANT: AB BW: 20Mhz MCS: 4 NSS: 1 NGI STBC`
```

Also, when fixing the rate by executing `echo "0x2C104" | tee >./rate_scale_table`, the bitrate as reported by  `iw dev wlp2s0 station dump` doesn't change. Why is that? Am I mixing up different (bit) rates? How to fix the birate (i.e. the MCS) of a dvm / mvm iwlwifi card?